# Commands to Uninstall amd Radeon gpu driver. Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon

Good day all,

1. I attempted to install the driver for my graphic card Radeon following the steps indicated on AMD page for Radeon.

https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-20

2. After I (1) downloaded of the file (2) "extracted here" (3) opened commands from the new folder and then (4) installed the file using the command " ./amdgpu-install ", (5) the computer froze at 97% of the installation. (6) I had to restart the computer
3. Reopening the computer, the Commands has as final message:

"The amdgpu driver is already installed or was not uninstalled correctly.
Please fully uninstall the driver before proceeding with installation
You can try running the amdgpu-uninstall or amdgpu-pro-uninstall script
present in /usr/bin to clean up the previous installation"

4. I am completely new to Ubuntu and Linux. Not sure what to do here. I believe I need to uninstall the driver before I can re-attempt the installation.

My Question is: What exactly I need to type on the command to do the amdgpu-uninstall ? Do I need to do this from  /usr/bin ? If yes, how to do this?

Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: First of all, why are you installing the proprietary overlay? If you don't have a valid reason then don't. `amdgpu`, the open source driver developed by AMD themselves is already installed automatically whenever compatible hardware is detected. This driver works better for almost all situations.

Comment: Well, it might be for the wrong reasons but (1) it was an advice I read "something you should after installing Ubuntu" (2) the name of the graphic card written in setting/about is "AMD® Raven" (3) a youtuber shows how to change your graphic card to "AMD@Radeon" by installing the file coming from https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-20 (4) I am guilty of wanting to play a demanding video-game (WOT). I did uninstall the 97%. I hope I did not mess anything. for now,  I ll leave it as it is. and attempt the game and check first if there is any problem.

Comment: For games, any game, the included driver works the same or better than the proprietary overlay. Conversely, for deep learning and other similarly intensive usages as well as for idiotic crypto mining, the proprietary overlay you tried to install may have a slight advantage but results vary, wildly. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My Question is: What exactly I need to type on the command to do the amdgpu-uninstall ? Do I need to do this from /usr/bin ? If yes, how to do this?

**The graphics driver `amdgpu` is already installed by default. It doesn't need to be manually installed and shouldn't be uninstalled.**

This open-source driver is already installed by default (in Ubuntu and derivatives as well as most major Linux distros) an is required for the AMD Graphics cards it supports. Unlike the proprietary overlay - **`amdgpu-pro`** - the default drivers don't require any user action for installation or updates.

The file you downloaded and tried to run can install one or the other. The command you used tries to install the same driver that was and is already in use, also available at the Ubuntu repository and updated whenever needed via the normal system updates. **No further user actions necessary**.

In a nutshell: What you did changed nothing and that's a good thing. As such no further actions are to be suggested. Enjoy your Ubuntu.